AzureRoomPanel - Door Panel clock isn't updating
Our Room/ Door Panel app for Meetingroom1@ account is not synchronised with the clock and is not updating automatically. Are you able to help, please? I have Relaunch the iPad
running Update from the orange dot top right corner

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
